# Proper way to return a map function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, map-function

I have the map function.

```
function test2() {
let data = [
            ["a","aa","aaa"],
            ["b","bb","bbb"],
            ["x","xx","xxx"],
            ["c","cc","ccc"]
           ];          
data.map(function(row){
          row[1]=row[1]+" ZZZ"
          row[2]=row[2]+" AAA"
  return  data
})
console.log(data)
}
```

I am unclear on the best way to return a map function
both these work

`return  data`

and

`return  row`

In my reading on map I think this is the correct way

`return  row`

What is the best way to return a map function?

Answer (score 4):

This is a misuse of `map`, so it doesn't matter here because you're ignoring the return value from `map`. If you inspect that, you'll see what the difference is.

```
let result = data.map(function(row){ return data });
console.log(result);

result = data.map(function(row){ return row });
console.log(result);
```

What you really want though is `forEach`:

```
data.forEach(function(row){
    row[1]=row[1]+" ZZZ"
    row[2]=row[2]+" AAA"
});
```

Or a normal `for` loop.

`map`'s purpose is to take an array and produce a new array as the result of running a function on each element. You only want to iterate to carry out side effects though.

Comment: Notice in the answer that `data.forEach()` is using a row array of `data`.  You are actually changing the values in `data` so you don't need to return anything.